# Init multiple Foundation Dropdowns using Knockout CustomBinding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, zurb-foundation, dropdown

I am trying to initialize a dropdown widget using Foundation. The actual html for the dropdown is compiled dynamically, and multiple dropdowns exist on the page. I am having trouble initializing the dropdowns because of their dynamic nature.

Essentially my question is, how do you initialize a Foundation dropdown without an ID or data-dropdown attribute?

I have a screen with a list of data "People" on the left, and a the details of a single person on the right. The whole screen is using Knockout to bind the data to the view model.

My main View model:

```
self.people = ko.observableArray([]); 
self.selectedPerson = ko.observable()
```

In my html:

```
<div data-bind='with: selectedPerson'>
    ...
    <div class='my-dropdown-widget' data-bind="myCustomBinding: {data: myData}">
          ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Each `selectedPerson` is a `Person` object, which has an `onReady` function that fires when the data from the person is rendered in the main view model. In that function, I have the following code:

```
self.onReady = function (el) {
    var filterEl = $('.filter-widget', el).attr({
        'id': self.filterWidget.ui_ID,
        'data-dropdown': ''
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(el).foundation();
    }, 500);

    self.ui_container = $(el);
};
```

I have to have the dropdown widget on the page (as opposed to loading the HTML for it) so i can apply bindings to it. Applying Bindings on dynamically loaded html messes up the widget's binding context.

This approach fails with the following message:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined**

This error usually occurs because the element does not have a data-dropdown attribute, which I am adding dynamically.

If I do this the way that is illustrated in the `Foundation` Docs, and add an ID and `data-dropdown` attribute to the dropdown element, the dropdown works, but only for the first `selectedPerson`. In other words, if I navigate to more than one person, the dropdown stops working properly.

How can I get these dropdowns to work given the setup of my page?

Comment: Can you add sample view/viewmodel, instead of snippet.